# If $|1-z^n|\le\frac12$, then $\frac1{2|1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}|}\le\frac1n$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

This should actually be a simple question: For $z\in\mathbb C$ with $$|1-z^n|\le\frac12\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag4$$ it follows from $$1-z^n=(1-z)(1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1})\tag5$$ that $$|1-z|\le\frac1{2|1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}|}\tag6,$$ but why is the rhs less than $n^{-1}$?

Maybe we need to use the inequality $(a_1+\cdots+a_n)^2\le n(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and the fact that $|z|\ge\Re|z|$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

**EDIT**: The following inequality can be found in the proof of Proposition 2.4.2 in Linde's *Probability in Banach Spaces: Stable and Infinitely Divisible Distributions*, but I don't understand why this inequality holds:

[image]

Comment: You must have $z=1$ if the above holds.

Comment: The question  makes more sense if you omit 'for all $n \in \mathbb N$' in (4).

Comment: @copper.hat Right, that's what I want to conclude at the end.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, "for all $n\in\mathbb N$" is important. See my comment above.

Comment: Only one $z$ satisfies that.

Comment: @$0$xbadf$00$d, I believe what Copper and Kavi are trying to say is that it is much more easily shown directly that $(4)$ is satisfied only by $z = 1$ than from this roundabout way you are proposing. Then the desired inequality follows.

Comment: @copper.hat Are you saying that the question in the title (with $n$ fixed) is wrong?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, just that if (4) holds then $z=1$.

Comment: Using triangle inequality we can prove that $|z|=1$

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @copper.hat Why? I'm not asking for a(n alternative) proof of $z=1$, but how we can show that the rhs of $(6)$ is $\le n^{-1}$ (from which we can deduce $z=1$). See my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how exactly the inequality above is defined if $Re(x) \neq x.$

Comment: @DerekLuna Which part do you think is undefined? The 2nd inequality in the excerpt is related to $|z|^2=(\Re z)^2+(\Im z)^2\ge(\Re z)^2$.

Comment: You have to say what the ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ is. Is it the linear order $a + bi \leq c+di$ iff $a \le c$ or $a=c$ and $b \leq d$ or what?

Comment: @DerekLuna You're obviously misreading the inequality. Every quantity in it belongs to $\mathbb R$; not $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Why is the polynomial $1+z+...+z^{n-1}$ not complex for complex $z$?

Comment: @DerekLuna It is complex, but in the inequality we are taking the length $|1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}|\in\mathbb R$ of it.

Comment: That is the right side of the inequality where there is the "Re" part. On the left side, it is simply the polynomial $|1+z+...+z^{n-1}|$. As you admit this part is possibly strictly complex, it is not obvious to me what to make of that middle inequality you have added.

Comment: @DerekLuna I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. It is **not** only the right-hand side. The inequality is $$\left(2\left|1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}\right|\right)^{-1}\le(2\Re(1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}))^{-1}.$$ Don't you see that we are taking the length of $1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1}$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, is the first inequality $|1-z^{n}|$ also the length?

Comment: @DerekLuna What else should it be?

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove the following slightly stronger statement: Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. If $|1-z^k|\leq \frac 1 2$ for $k\leq n-1$, then
$$
\mathrm{Re}(1+z+\dots+z^{n-1})\geq \frac n 2.
$$
In fact, $\mathrm{Re}(z^k)=1-\mathrm{Re}(1-z^k)\geq 1-|1-z^k|\geq \frac 1 2$. This readily implies the desired inequality.

Comment: Btw, if we only assume $|1-z^n|\leq \frac 1 2$ for fixed $n$ as suggested in one of the comments, then the conclusion does not hold any longer. Take $z=-1$ and $n=2$ for example.

Comment: i am surprised why this hasnt recieved an upvote yet(+1)